# Doesn't display salary from given table to created column, wrong SELECT AND WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In the "Positions" dictionary, you need to add an additional column "Position salary". The value of this field is taken from the "Amount" field from the payroll table "salary", and all this must be on the current system date (current)

WHAT IS AVAILABLE

There is a dictionary `"Positions" (POSITIONS)`, in which you need to add the field Amount (SUMM) from the table `POSITIONSFOT (Positions (wage fund))`. There is also an `OKLZP` table `(Composition)`, where in the `NAME` field you need to select the value '1.salary' and display exactly those amounts that relate specifically to the value `NAME='1.salary'`.

The function compiled, but shows nothing, even though the SUMM value has zeros. Although the table has 0. In the code below, I am trying to find the record number `(RN)` of the `"Positions (wage fund)"` table, given the condition that its record numbers match the 'Positions' table and matches the name '1.salary'

```
FUNCTION CODE:

create or replace function view_SALAR
(
NRN NUMBER
) 
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  INRN NUMBER;
  NUMVAL NUMBER; --- variable for selecting values and returning from the function
BEGIN
  INRN:=NRN;
  BEGIN 
    SELECT POSFOT.SUMM INTO NUMVAL 
    FROM 
    POSITIONSFOT POSFOT, --- table "Positions (wage fund)"
   POSITIONS POSIT, --- table "Positions"   
    OKLZP OKL, --- table "Composition of payroll", from where we take the exact name of the type of wages (salary)
    STAFFPOSITIONS  STAFFPOS ---table "full positions", where you need to take Date from(DO_ACT_FROM) and date by(DO_ACT_TO) to get the system date
    WHERE
    POSIT.RN= INRN 
    AND POSIT.RN=POSFOT.RN
    AND OKL.NAME='1. salary'
    AND STAFFPOS.DO_ACT_FROM<=SYSDATE AND (STAFFPOS.DO_ACT_FROM>SYSDATE OR STAFFPOS.DO_ACT_TO IS NULL); 
  END;
  return NUMVAL;
end view_SALAR;
```

why do i need help or explanation?

Help me understand my mistake when drafting the request and conditions. All the tables that I have listed are interconnected through the `RN` record number.

The function compiles, there are no error messages. The column is created, but there are no values in the field. It is quite possible that I write `SELECT` incorrectly or the conditions themselves after `WHERE`.

If you do not have information, i can supplement my quesstion.

Comment: Do you get any result if you run that SELECT outside of the function, hardcoding the INRN value?

Comment: Using all capitals and excessive use of bold comes across as shouting, which is pretty rude to do when asking people for help.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and the expected output for the question.

Comment: Also, the question is to "add an additional column"; it is unclear why the solution is not simply `ALTER TABLE positions ADD position_salary NUMBER;` and then perform an `UPDATE` statement to populate it. Why you think that you need to write a function?